# If we could reach very high speeds, could we measure the velocity of the Earth this way?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, velocity

If we could reach (nearly) the speed of light with spaceships, could we measure the velocity of the Earth by launching three perpendicular rockets, accelerating them, and measuring how much fuel (energy) they needed to reach their maximum speed?

Alternately, could we measure the velocity of Earth by emitting photons instead of launching rockets, and looking for colour shifting?

Comment: Velocity of earth with respect to what?

Comment: I would guess you're thinking the speed of light represents an absolute maximum velocity for the whole universe, so if you can measure the Earth's velocity relative to the speed of light you'd get a figure for the Earth's velocity. If so, I'm afraid your initial assumption is wrong. The difference between any observer and the speed light travels is always $c$, regardless of that observer's motion. So the speed of light relative to the Earth is just $c$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first idea would work if it was possible to accelerate a rocket to the speed of light rather than only being able to approach the speed of light. But a person on a rocket moving at $.99c$ relative to Earth will still look out his window and see photons zipping past at the speed of light, *not* at $.01c$. Since it would require infinite energy supplied to a massive object to accelerate it to $c$, all that you would find is that all your rockets used as much fuel as you could possibly give them and still didn't reach $c$.

Your second idea is actually much better. The hard part here is setting up stations to receive the photons that are "at rest", whatever that means. At rest with respect to what? Not the Earth obviously. The Sun? The centre of the Galaxy? The Local Group centre of mass? The cosmic microwave background rest frame? At the very least you'll want stations that are at rest with respect to each other, which in the context of general relativity is more subtle than is immediately apparent. For some of the difficulties around setting up such stations see pt. 4 of [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/45465/11053).

But, supposing you managed to set up such stations, your scheme works perfectly. If you know the emitted frequency of the light - which is easy, suppose you use a laser of known frequency - then the received frequency gives the velocity easily through the relationship:

$$\frac{\nu_{\rm emitted}}{\nu_{\rm received}} \approx \frac{v_{\rm LoS}}{c}$$

This is an approximation that is quite good as long as the earth is not moving close to the speed of light (relative to your measuring stations). $v_{\rm LoS}$ is the velocity of the Earth along the line between the Earth and the measuring station, so if you have three stations that are not co-planar, you can measure the entire velocity vector of the Earth.

If you wanted a very accurate measurement there are some additional corrections to worry about, for instance the Earth's gravity would also contribute a small frequency shift to the laser light, which you could correct for provided you knew the mass distribution of the Earth.

Incidentally, this Doppler shift of light is the most common technique astronomers use to measure the velocities of astrophysical objects. The trouble is that we only have one measuring station (Earth), so we can only get one component of the velocity vector with this method, which causes us no end of frustration.